# Python mechanize checkboxes

Tags: python, automation, mechanize, www-mechanize

I want to do this using Python Mechanize.
This is HTML page:

```
<form action="config.php" method="POST">
<div>
<img src="/images/delete1.png" />
<strong>EmptyDir1</strong><br />
<input type="checkbox"  value="3" name="manager[]" />
</div>

<div>
<img src="/images/delete2.png" />
<strong>EmptyDir2</strong><br />
<input type="checkbox"  value="4" name="manager[]" />
</div>

<div>
<img src="/images/copy.png" />
<strong>CopyConf</strong><br />
<input type="checkbox"  value="22" name="manager[]" />
</div>
................. and so on another 20

<div><input type="submit" value="Do Jobs!" /></div>
</form>
```

I have 2 questions:
1. How can I select all the checkboxes from this page and submit them?
2. How can I select all the checkboxes, except the one with name "modify"?
A sample of code will be great. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this for every checkbox:

```
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open(URL)
br.select_form(nr=0)
for i in range(0, len(br.find_control(type="checkbox").items)):
    br.find_control(type="checkbox").items[i].selected =True
reponse = br.submit()
print reponse.read()
```

And this for all except modify checkboxes (haven't checked it):

```
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open(URL)
br.select_form(nr=0)
for i in range(0, len(br.find_control(type="checkbox").items)):
    if "modify" not in str(br.find_control(type="checkbox").items[i]):
        br.find_control(type="checkbox").items[i].selected =True
reponse = br.submit()
print reponse.read()
```

Comment: Thanks. Works great the first part. But not the second one.

Comment: Can you give me website on which you are testing? Or post what is the output if you try to  execute `print br.find_control(type="checkbox").items` before the `for` loop

Comment: I put it like this and its working perfectly. Thanks a lot. for i in range(0, len(br.find_control(type="checkbox").items)):
    if "modify" in str(br.find_control(type="checkbox").items[i]):
        br.find_control(type="checkbox").items[i].selected = False
    else:
        br.find_control(type="checkbox").items[i].selected = True
reponseaa = br.submit()